# Is there any way to prioritize Gamma function?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, special-functions

In Mathematica, if you type

```
Gamma[1, 0, -a]
```

It automatically simplifies to `1 - E^a`. I wonder though if there is a way to stop Mathematica from simplify Gamma function automatically.

I understand that I can use `Inactive` or `HoldFrom`. But I actually want having to remember using Inactive every time.

Comment: You could put this `$PreRead = 
  ReplaceAll[#, 
    RowBox[{"Gamma", "[", RowBox[{"1", ",", "0", ",", x_}], "]"}] :> 
     TagBox[RowBox[{"Gamma", "[", RowBox[{"1", ",", "0", ",", x}], 
        "]"}], HoldForm]] &;` into your init.m file ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define your own function.

```
Clear["Global`*"]

gamma[x__] := Module[{g = Gamma[x]},
  If[FreeQ[g, _Gamma], Inactive[Gamma][x], g]]

gamma /@ {6, x}

(* {Inactive[Gamma][6], Gamma[x]} *)

gamma @@@ {{1, z}, {a, z}}

(* {Inactive[Gamma][1, z], Gamma[a, z]} *)

gamma @@@ {{1, 0, -a}, {a, z0, z1}} *)

(* {Inactive[Gamma][1, 0, -a], Gamma[a, z0, z1]}
```